# How to access function inside methods of mixin from component lifecycle method in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

Here is an example :

mixin.js

```
export default {
    methods : {
        aFunction() { // Some functionality here }
    }
}
```

component.vue

```
import mixin from './mixin'
export default {
    mixins : [ mixin ]
    created() {
        // Call aFunction defined in the mixin here
    }
}
```

I want to access the aFunction defined inside methods of mixin from the created() lifecycle method inside the component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mixin methods are merged with the current instance of the component, so it would just be:

```
created(){
  this.aFunction()
}
```

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

const mixin = {
  methods:{
    aFunction(){
      console.log("called aFunction")
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  mixins:[mixin],
  created(){
    this.aFunction()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason the function is being called 3 times ?

Comment: @gaurav4sarma Where? Here it's called once. In your code maybe, if the component is created more than once.

Comment: yes that might be it. How to structure the flow for it to be called only once I am mean is there a way to make it call only once because its making an API call to get data

Comment: @gaurav4sarma I'm sure there are several ways but it's difficult to guess without code. I'd suggest asking a different question with you particular structure.